# Theme seems to be preventing me from adding a new page to my site

Tags: themes, wp-admin

I have recently joined my company and have been asked to update our website.  The site was built by a external dev company using a custom theme which seems to be blocking the editing of new pages.  In WP /Pages I can add an additional page which I can access through the url but I am unable to save any content to the page.  The designer has used Custom Fields and the new page does show these in the edit page view. I can enter text in the text control but it isn't visible in the preview and won't save when I update.  I have been through all the theme files and can't see how the developer might have blocked the editing of additional pages which basically means he has blocked any editing of the site which is owned by us. That seems irregular to me and I don't even know if it's possible because I am not an expert.

So my question is, is it possible?  And if it isn't would someone kindly point me in the right direction as to how I might 'unlock' editing of new pages.  If it's not something in the theme files then what have I missed in WP and if it is something in the theme files, what could it be?  Many thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

Comment: I've worked on a site where the requirement was to build the page only from data in custom fields and ignore the text edit control - maybe that's what you've got here? The best solution is to talk to the original dev company and ask them - hopefully someone who worked on the project would be happy to exchange emails or give you a quick call. Or to investigate yourself I'd work out which template from the theme is being used for your new page and then pick through that to see how it's expecting to put content on the page, and why there's no `the_content()` or similar in there.

Comment: Or you can always add a new template for your new page (or pages in general) fixed up to avoid disturbing the existing site. It's also worth checking for script errors in your browser in case the page is supposed to be assembled by script and that's failing on your new page for whatever reason.

Comment: Oh I missed you said not saving. If it's actually not saving, that could also be a filter in a custom plugin that overrides some of the save and update hooks and rejects the save or clears the main text control. It'd be worth checking those if you have any too.

Comment: Or, as a very long shot, it could be database triggers rejecting the update or clearing fields. If you really can't find it anywhere else that might be worth a look. But hopefully if you talk to someone who knows the project you can figure this out.

Comment: You asked about triggers: look at your database in MySQL Workbench or similar and there's a list of the triggers per table in the schema view. This is code you can attach to the table to take action when rows are added, updated, deleted etc., and it would be possible to put a trigger on wp_post that clears out the contents or rejects the update. But I can't imagine anyone has done that.